# Removing Multiple UIImageView with the same name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I created an `UIImageView` multiple times base on how many users tap the screen like this

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.imageView];

    fadeSpotRect = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x-20, touchPoint.y-20, 40, 40);

    UIImageView *fadeSpotImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:fadeSpotRect];

    UIImage *fadeImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];

    fadeImage = [filter smoothenPores:[self croppIngimageByImageName:faceImage toRect:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x-20, touchPoint.y-20, 40, 40)] intensity:10];

    fadeImage = [self maskImage:fadeImage withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fadeMask.png"]];

    fadeSpotImageView.image = fadeImage;

    [self.imageView addSubview:fadeSpotImageView];
}
```

Now if I call [fadeSpotImageView removeFromSuperview] it only remove the last UIImageView I created. I want to remove all the `UIImageView` I created. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options - I prefer option 1 because it is the most explicit, clean, and very importantly documents itself.

1:  Declare a property for a NSMutableArray and alloc and init it with the rest of your initialization code.  Then whenever you create a new UIImageView in add it to your array, for example

```
self.imageViews addObject: fadeSpotImageView];
```

Then when your ready to remove all of them enumerate through the array and remove them all, then clear the array

```
[self.imageView enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImageView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}];

[self.imageViews removeAllObjects];
```

2:  You could blindly remove all subviews which are UIImageViews.  This is simple but you have to be sure your not removing views that you actually want to keep.

```
[self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [obj removeFromSuperview];
    }
}];
```

3:  As an extension to option 2 you could tag all your imageViews when you create them and then use that as your condition check in the loop instead.  This has the drawback that now you need to keep track of the tag you assigned your views and make sure it doesn't conflict with something else (which is unlikely but could happen).

```
//put in your touchesBegan method
fadeSpotImageView.tag = 100 //arbitrary number chosen to id the imageview

//then put this as your condition
if (obj.tag == 100)
{
    [obj removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I use the option 1 and it work like a charm. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fast enumeration:

Call: `[self removeImageViews];`

```
- (void)removeImageViews
{
    for (UIImageView *sub in self.imageView.subviews)
    {
        [sub removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```